# a connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond python

Tags: ldap

I am trying to connect to LDAP.
server = Server('LDAP://url', get_info=ALL)
conn = Connection(server, auto_bind= True)

when I run this i get an error:
"a connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond...."
[WinError 10060]

Kindly help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the client cannot reach the server.

Is 'LDAP://url' the real address of the server you are trying to connect to?

Comment: Yes, the url is the real url of the server